# Why does len([1,[2,[3]]]]) return 2, while len([1,[2]]) also return 2?

Tags: python, recursion, average

I'm trying to write a function, `def list_average(list_input)`, that takes a list such as `[1, 2, 3]` or `[1,[2,[3]]]]` and returns the average of the integers in the list; however, when I use `len([1,[2,[3]]]])` to find the number of integers in the list, it returns 2. Can anyone explain?

My code is as follows:

```
def list_average(list_input):
    n = sumaverage(list_input)
    count = len(list_input)
    if count == 0:
        return 0
    average = n / count
    return int(average)
```

Comment: Its because the length of the outer list is 2. If you do `len(your_list[1])` it will give you the length of the inner list. To address that, you will have to unwrap the list.

Comment: The list has 2 items, `1` and `[2,[3]]` (Though you have an extra ']')

Comment: `[1,[2,[3]]]` contains 2 elements `1` and `[2,[3]]`. `[1,[2]]` also contains 2 elements `1` and `[2]`. `len()` will not count the sub lists.

Comment: Because they are both lists with length 2! `[1,[2,[3]]]]` is a list with two elements, the `int` object `1` and another list. Similarly,  `[1,[2]]` is a list with an `int`, 1, and another list. `len` doesn't "recursively count how many int objects are contained in your list, and any objects inside of that list". It just gives you *the length of the list*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`len` returns the length of the top level sequence only. If the elements in that sequence happen to *also* be sequences, that is not considered.

```
>>> len([1,2,3])              # list of 3 ints
3
>>> len([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]])  # list of 3 sub-lists
3
>>> len([1, [2,3], [[4,5,6], [7,8,9]]])  # list of mixed types, some are themselves lists
3
```

If you're after something like "how many non-list elements are in my list" you could do something recursive like

```
def recursive_len(data):
    if isinstance(data, list):
        return sum(recursive_len(i) for i in data)
    else:
        return 1

>>> recursive_len([1,2,3])
3
>>> recursive_len([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]])
6
>>> recursive_len([1, [2,3], [[4,5,6], [7,8,9]]])
9
```

Comment: I see! Just wondering, but is there a function like index() that I would be able to use to find the number of integers in a list? I know I can recursively look at the type of each item in `list_input` and then append the integers to a separate list and then len(separate_list), I'm just wondering if there's a shorter method. Thank you!

Comment: @AlbertLee no, you have to implement a solution yourself. A `list` is a sequence of objects, the fact that one of those objects is a container isn't relevant from the perspective of the list API.

Answer (score 2):

`len([1,[2,[3]]]])` has a list with two elements as input: the first element of the list is the integer `1` and the second element is the list `[2,[3]]`.